# Longjing tea in English

Tags: culture

In China there is a kind of tea called *Longjing*. But can we call it Dragon Well tea? Because I heard that in foreign countries a dragon does not have a positive image.

Comment: Many Chinese words may not be translated character by character, for the name itself had a long history, and some names are abbreviated words. The word 龙井 means **the water well** (井) that a **loong** (龙, Chinese dragon) lives in, if you translated as **Dragon Well**, it is an ambiguous name. Also, the province name 江苏, comes from the city names 江宁 and 苏州.

Comment: 很好喝的茶，我每天都喝完整壶龙井茶！ 问题：一条住在井里的龙不是鱼吗？为什么不叫‘鱼井茶’？

Answer (score 1):

No, Longjing is a term of tea. It is a specific type of tea.

If you talk to people Dragon Well, they don't think you are talking about tea but a real well called Dragon.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what the question is asking, but here’s what I’ve pieced together anyway:

[Babelcarp](http://www.panix.com/%7Eperin/babelcarp/babelcarp.cgi?phrase=%E9%BE%99%E4%BA%95&define=1) does have this entry:

> **Translation**
>
> 龙井 (Long2 Jing3) = (龙井 or 龍井) Dragon well (wok-fired flat-leaf lücha, canonically from Xi Hu in Zhejiang)

I would assume in some circles it’s a *valid* translation but I wouldn’t know which circles those would be.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longjing_tea) also mentions:

> Longjing tea.....sometimes called by its literal translated name **Dragon Well tea**, is a variety of pan-roasted green tea from the area of Longjing Village near Hangzhou in Zhejiang Province, China.

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FUUN01U) (USA) is also selling:

> Golden Moon Tea - Dragon Well Tea - Organic - Loose Leaf - Non GMO - 2oz Tin - 24 Servings

With the words **Dragon Well** printed largely on the label.